# psexec command runs locally instead of remotely

Tags: powershell, psexec

I am trying to use psexec to download an installer and then execute the installer on a remote VM, but the command passed to psexec runs locally instead of remotely

When I run

```
PS > psexec \\RemoteVmName -u VmAdminUsername -p VmAdminPassword powershell (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("http://ServerAddress:8080/MyInstaller.msi", "C:/installer.msi")
```

**Expected Behavior**

File gets downloaded to `C:/installer.msi` on the `remote machine`

**Observed Behavior**

File gets downloaded to `C:/installer.msi` on the `local machine`, the machine where psexec is being called from

---

Running psexec into a powershell prompt and then calling the download file method gets the desired behavior, but I need this to run without manual steps.

**Works Manually**

```
PS > psexec \\RemoteVmName -u VmAdminUsername -p VmAdminPassword powershell
PS > (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("http://ServerAddress:8080/MyInstaller.msi", "C:/installer.msi")
```

That gets the installer on the remote machine but requires human input. I need to do the same without human input.

Using the `-i` and `-h` flags are not helping.

Comment: Why don't you utilize PSSessions over psexec? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/new-pssession#example-2-create-a-session-on-a-remote-computer

Comment: Why use PSEXEC at all? Why not just do `invoke-command -computername $computername -scriptblock { (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("http://ServerAddress:8080/MyInstaller.msi", "C:/installer.msi") } `

Comment: you can also append credentials with `-credential`